# Error con llamar el DefaultTableModel (jtable.getmodel) de una tabla de otro formulario

Tags: java-swing, jtable

Tengo un método de pasar los datos de un tabla a otra tabla para pero me genera error cuando llamo la tabla a pasar los datos. Hago todo el procedimiento normal (como todos hacen para pasar datos de tabla a otra tabla). Que es lo que falta o lo que estoy haciendo mal?
Codigo:

```
public void PasarFilas() {
        int[] seleccionados = jTable2.getSelectedRows();
        DefaultTableModel model1,model2;
        model1 = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();//tabla donde quiero extraer los datos.
        Object[] fila = new Object[3];
        model2 = (DefaultTableModel) vCompras_Insumos.jTable1.getModel();//tabla donde quiero almacenar los datos, sin embargo aqui me dice que es el error.
        for (int i = 0; i < seleccionados.length; i++) {
            //iddetalle = jTable2.getValueAt(j, 0).toString();
            fila[0] = model1.getValueAt(seleccionados[i], 4);
            fila[1] = model1.getValueAt(seleccionados[i], 5);
            fila[2] = model1.getValueAt(seleccionados[i], 6);
            model2.addRow(fila);
        }
        if (compra == null || compra.isClosed()) {
            compra = new vCompras_Insumos();
            vMenuPrincipal.jDesktopPane1.add(compra);
            compra.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            compra.toFront();
            compra.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

El metodo lo llamo mediante un boton y me genera el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Vistas.vListas_Compras.PasarFilas(vListas_Compras.java:98)
    at Vistas.vListas_Compras.jButton4ActionPerformed(vListas_Compras.java:459)
    at Vistas.vListas_Compras.access$400(vListas_Compras.java:22)
    at Vistas.vListas_Compras$9.actionPerformed(vListas_Compras.java:324)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

El error apunta a esto:

```
model2 = (DefaultTableModel) vCompras_Insumos.jTable1.getModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar todo eso, solo crea una función que te devuelva un arreglo bidimensional del contenido de tu tabla, por ejemplo si los datos en tu tabla son String:

```
public String[][] obtenerContenido(JTable tabla){
//El tamaño de tu arreglo lo defines con el numero de filas y columnas
            String[][] aux = new String[tabla.getRowCount()][tabla.getColumnCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < tabla.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tabla.getRowCount(); j++) {
                    aux[i][j] = (String) tabla.getModel().getValueAt(i, j);
                }
            }
            return aux;
        }
```

y los manipulas a tu gusto.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion a esto, es algo bastante simple que no se si alguien ha pasado dejar este detalle..

```
public void PasarFilas() {
        if (compra == null || compra.isClosed()) {
            compra = new vCompras_Insumos();
            vMenuPrincipal.jDesktopPane1.add(compra);
            compra.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            compra.toFront();
            compra.setVisible(true);
        }
        int[] seleccionados = jTable2.getSelectedRows();
        Object[] fila = new Object[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < seleccionados.length; i++) {
            fila[0] = datosdetalle.getValueAt(seleccionados[i], 4);
            fila[1] = datosdetalle.getValueAt(seleccionados[i], 5);
            fila[2] = datosdetalle.getValueAt(seleccionados[i], 6);
            vCompras_Insumos.modelo.addRow(fila);
        }
    }
```

Como podran observar, simplemente lo que hago es que se habilite PRIMERO el jinternalframe donde esta la tabla sobre lo cual quiero volcar los datos y luego hago el procedimiento normal de ingresar a la tabla para extraer los mismos.

Lo se, es algo insignificante. Disculpen mi ignorancia sobre estos temas..

Por cierto, Chris Vazquez muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta, tu solucion tambien es valida. Saludos!